# copying directory from local system to hdfs java code

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm having a problem trying to copy a directory from my local system to HDFS using java code. I'm able to move individual files but can't figure out a way to move an entire directory with sub-folders and files. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using? `bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal folder` copies `folder` and recursively everything in it just fine for me.

Comment: because directory is not a 'file'. you should create directory recursively and move file one by one (you can do it in parallel, if you wish). Of course, you should be aware, that this operation not atomic, so if you fail, some files left ufinished on hdfs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use the `FileSystem`'s [copyFromLocalFile](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyFromLocalFile%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29) method. If the source Path is a local directory it will be copied to the HDFS destination:

```
...
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/user/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/user/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/home/user/directory/"), 
  new Path("/user/hadoop/dir"));
...
```

Comment: the path for hdfs which i am providing is of the form "hdfs://cluster.abc.com:8080/user/something", but it says "wrong FS, expected file:///". Any help for this?

Comment: Which value do you have in core-site.xml for fs.default.name ? It should point to hdfs://host[:port]

Comment: thanks. setting fs.default.name to the required hdfs://host:port worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working code to read and write in to HDFS. It takes two arguments

1. Input path ( local / HDFS )
2. Output path(HDFS)

I used Cloudera sandbox.

```
 package hdfsread;

 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.net.URI;

 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;

 public class ReadingAFileFromHDFS {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         String uri = args[0];
         InputStream in = null;
         Path pt = new Path(uri);
         Configuration myConf = new Configuration();
         Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

         myConf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020");
         FileSystem fSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri),myConf);
         OutputStream os = fSystem.create(outputPath);
         try{
             InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(uri));
             IOUtils.copyBytes(is, os, 4096, false);
         }
         catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally{
             IOUtils.closeStream(in);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi when i try this one i am getting org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream error. I have added hadoop-common, hadoop-hdfs libraries to my pom. and also added core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml to my configuration.