# Upload data to HDFS with Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I've searched for some time now and none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Pretty straightforward - I want to upload data from my local file system to HDFS using the Java API.  The Java program will be run on a host that has been configured to talk to a remote Hadoop cluster through shell (i.e. `hdfs dfs -ls`, etc.).

I have included the below dependencies in my project:

```
hadoop-core:1.2.1
hadoop-common:2.7.1
hadoop-hdfs:2.7.1
```

I have code that looks like the following:

```
 File localDir = ...;
 File hdfsDir = ...;
 Path localPath = new Path(localDir.getCanonicalPath());
 Path hdfsPath = new Path(hdfsDir.getCanonicalPath());
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
 conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
 Filesystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
 fs.getFromLocalFile(localPath, hdfsPath);
```

The local data is not being copied to the Hadoop cluster, but no errors are reported and no exceptions are thrown.  I've enabled `TRACE` logging for the `org.apache.hadoop` package.  I see the following outputs:

```
 DEBUG Groups:139 -  Creating new Groups object
 DEBUG Groups:139 -  Creating new Groups object
 DEBUG Groups:59 - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping; cacheTimeout=300000
 DEBUG Groups:59 - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping; cacheTimeout=300000
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:147 - hadoop login
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:147 - hadoop login
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:96 - hadoop login commit
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:96 - hadoop login commit
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:126 - using local user:UnixPrincipal: willra05
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:126 - using local user:UnixPrincipal: willra05
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:558 - UGI loginUser:<username_redacted>
 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:558 - UGI loginUser:<username_redacted>
 DEBUG FileSystem:1441 - Creating filesystem for file:///
 DEBUG FileSystem:1441 - Creating filesystem for file:///
 DEBUG FileSystem:1290 - Removing filesystem for file:///
 DEBUG FileSystem:1290 - Removing filesystem for file:///
 DEBUG FileSystem:1290 - Removing filesystem for file:///
 DEBUG FileSystem:1290 - Removing filesystem for file:///
```

Can anyone assist in helping me resolve this issue?

**EDIT 1: (09/15/2015)**

I've removed 2 of the Hadoop dependencies - I'm only using one now:

```
hadoop-core:1.2.1
```

My code is now the following:

```
File localDir = ...;
File hdfsDir = ...;
Path localPath = new Path(localDir.getCanonicalPath());
Path hdfsPath = new Path(hdfsDir.getCanonicalPath());
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
fs.getFromLocalFile(localPath, hdfsPath);
```

I was previously executing my application with the following command:

```
$ java -jar <app_name>.jar <app_arg1> <app_arg2> ...
```

Now I'm executing it with this command:

```
$ hadoop jar <app_name>.jar <app_arg1> <app_arg2> ...
```

*With these changes, my application now interacts with HDFS as intended.*  To my knowledge, the `hadoop jar` command is meant only for Map Reduce jobs packaged as an executable jar, but these changes did the trick for me.

Comment: hadoop command include hadoop classes in the classpath and if it is necessary unjar the jar and repackage it to include some libraries. At the enh the haddop command will execute the java command but with the extra objects/configurations.

Comment: I've already packaged my program as a fat jar using the Maven Shade plugin.  Were you referring to something else?  If so, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about the approach you are following, but below is one way data can be uploaded to hdfs using java libs :

```
//imports required 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

//some class here .....
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", <hdfs write endpoint>);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(<src>, <dst>);
```

Also if you have hadoop conf xmls locally, you can include them in you class path. Then hadoop fs details will automatically be picked up at runtime, and you will not need to set "fs.defaultFS" . Also if you are running in old hdfs version you might need to use "fs.default.name" instead of "fs.defaultFS". If you are not sure of the hdfs endpoint, it is usually the hdfs namenode url . Here is example from previous similar question [copying directory from local system to hdfs java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783968/copying-directory-from-local-system-to-hdfs-java-code)

Comment: My program is packaged as a fat jar using the Maven Shade plugin.  I notice that if I try to execute the jar with `$ java -jar <program_name>.jar` the program doesn't execute as intended, but if I execute the jar with `$ hadoop jar <program_name>.jar` it does what I intended.  Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If you are creating a Hadoop client, it could be better to add **hadoop-client** dependency. It includes all the sub-modules required dependencies. https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/2087eaf684d9fb14b5390e21bf17e93ac8fea7f8/hadoop-client/pom.xml. Unless the size of the Jar is a concern and if you are very sure that you won't require another dependency.
2. When you execute a job using `hadoop` command the class that it is executed is `RunJar` and not your driver class. Then RunJar executes your job. For more details you can see the code here: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/2087eaf684d9fb14b5390e21bf17e93ac8fea7f8/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/RunJar.java#L139

If you review the `createClassLoader` method in the `RunJar` class, you will notice that several locations are being included in the **classpath**.

Then, if you are executing your class directly using the **java -jar** command you could be ignoring all the other required steps to execute your job in hadoop that **hadoop jar** are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Let me take a step back for a second: should I even be using the `hadoop jar` command to run my program?  My program does interact with the HDFS, but it isn't a Map Reduce job.  From my understanding, the `hadoop jar` command is for running Map Reduce jobs.  It just so happens that my program's code gets execute properly with this command (as opposed to the `java -jar` command) because certain other things are added to the classpath.

Comment: If your project doesn't require to run in a **distributed environment** (MapReduce or Yarn) then it is NOT necessary to execute it using **hadoop jar**. You only need to be sure that the **hadoop-client** dependency is included in your project. For me, the easy way to do it is using **maven** to manage the dependencies. executing the project with the statement: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.module.Main"`

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion.  After switching to `hadoop-client`, I ended up getting an `IOException` about the `HADOOP_HOME` and/or `hadoop.home.dir` not being set.  Am I missing some extra configuration that needs to occur now that I'm using `java -jar` instead of `hadoop jar`?

Answer (score 0):

Kasa, you need to use the method

```
public static FileSystem get(URI uri,Configuration conf)
```

to get `fs`, the uri params is necessary if you use `java -jar` command.