# Use application configuration over Hadoop configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, log4j, hdfs, slf4j

I have built a Java application using Maven.  It is packaged as an executable jar using the Maven Shade plugin.  This application does several things - one of those is to upload data to a Hadoop cluster.  I execute the program using the following:

```
$ hadoop jar <app_name>.jar <app_arg1> <app_arg2> ...
```

**My application uses SLF4J with the Log4J bindings for logging - *and so does Hadoop*.**

When using the `hadoop jar` command, Hadoop's own Log4J configuration file overrides my application's Log4J configuration file.

***How can I prevent my application's Log4J configuration file from being overriden?***

*NOTES:*

- Relevant dependencies: `hadoop-core:1.2.1`, `slf4j-api:1.7.12`, and `slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12`.
- I'm using the `hadoop jar` command, instead of `java -jar`.  My application code that interacts with the Hadoop cluster only works when using the `hadoop jar` command.  I've outlined this issue in [a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399075/upload-data-to-hdfs-with-java-api).

**EDIT 1: (10/02/2015)**

I've done a few things.

First, I changed the name of my Log4J configuration file to avoid the name collision with the the default `log4j.properties` file that Hadoop uses:

```
log4j-<app_name>.properties
```

Second, I set the the `HADOOP_OPTS` environment variable to tell Log4J what the name of my configuration file would be:

```
HADOOP_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configurationi=log4j-<app_name>.properties
```

Third, I set the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable to ensure my configuration file that is packaged within the uber jar is picked up by the `hadoop jar` command:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/absolute/path/to/<app_name>.jar
```

With these changes, my application now uses it's own Log4J configuration file as intended.  Feels like a hack (as I would have preferred to use the `java -jar` command), but it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default Hadoop framework jars appear before the users’ jars in the `classpath`. You can set the preference for your (user) jars using **`-Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true`** parameter in the command. The new command will look below.

```
hadoop jar <app_name>.jar -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true <<app_arg1>> <<app_arg2>> ...
```

Or You can put the below configuration in your `mapred-site.xml` for always giving preference to user `classpath`.

```xml
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

You can set this programmatically in the job configuration.

```
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first", "true");
```

You can set this via any way, it will never be late.

Comment: Is there a way that I can set this programmatically?  Or would doing it programmatically be to late in the process to override the necessary configuration?

Comment: @Kasa You can set this programmatically. I have updated the same in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The options you've mentioned are not working for me.  Any other suggestions would be great, but if not, how should I start debugging further?

Comment: @Kasa These were the ways to give preference to the user jar then hadoop jars. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error on my end.  My log4j.properties configuration was just never picked up it seems.  I'm unsure how to debug further, any advice can help.  Your suggestions seem accurate based on research other places but there must be something off that I can't determine since there aren't any errors being produced.