# Does HDFS support special characters (Umlauts, etc..)?

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs, redhat, hue

I am trying to add a file with umlauts to hdfs but when I do I get an error message like this below

```
++ hdfs dfs -put $'data/R\366\337el.doc' solr/test/test.data
put: `test.data/Rï¿½ï¿½el.doc': No such file or directory
```

What should I do then ? Translate the files with ä for example to ae or is there another way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDFS stores these strings using Java whose strings are UTF-16 encoded. On the wire Hadoop's RPC uses UTF-8 which contains umlauts and various other characters.

What you've probably encountered is that your shell does not seem to support the encoding or the characters.

When in doubt, you can always use the Java API to put files into HDFS, which requires to write some code.

Comment: Do you have a link or example in Java and Python ?

Comment: @Mensch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399075/upload-data-to-hdfs-with-java-api

Comment: @Mensch Python no clue.