# “Wrong FS… expected: file:///” when trying to copyFromLocalFile from HDFS in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to copy **abc.json** from **port/example_File/2017** to another location **/port/example_File/2018** in HDFS,
by below code

```
String exampleFile= "hdfs://port/example_File/2017/abc.json"
String targetFile="hdfs://port/example_File/2018"
hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(exampleFile),new Path(targetFile))
```

I am getting below exception

```
    org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:
 hdfs://port/example_File/2017/abc.json, expected: file:///
```

How to copy file from one location to another in HDFS

Thanks,

Comment: May The following link help you...
Please check.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783968/copying-directory-from-local-system-to-hdfs-java-code

Comment: It is a different scenario in my case, I cannot us **set fs.default.name to the required hdfs://host:port**, Because I will deploy in many servers. Also I am copying many files with this @JBhanushali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyFromLocal` is to copy files from Local Filesystem to HDFS.

To copy files within an HDFS cluster, use [`FileUtil.copy()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)) and specify same Filesystem for both `srcFS` and `dstFs`.

Use [`DistCp`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) when copying large number of files within a HDFS cluster or between two different HDFS clusters. Refer DistCp Java API [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/tools/DistCp.html).

Comment: I tried with **FileUtil.copy(new File(f.getPath().toString()),hdfs,new Path(target_filepath),false,conf);** But I got   **org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.io.IOException: hdfs:/port/example_File/2017/abc.json No such file or directory**  Actually it should starts with **hdfs://port/** when I print **f.getPath().toString()** it giving same. But when it is trying to copy it is taking as **hdfs:/port** Any reason for this ? @franklinsijo

Comment: @Ganesh Pass the source FileSystem also and omit the URI. Just pass `/example_File/2017/abc.json` for src path. Like `FileUtil.copy(hdfs, new Path("/example_File/2017/abc.json"),hdfs,new Path(target_filepath),false,conf);`