# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:9000 expected: file:///

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am struggling in hadoop commands for copy,delete,rename & move. I am getting following error while running copy. I have checked other similar answers too but not successful.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/new1, expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:390)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:55)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.pathToFile(LocalFileSystem.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.exists(LocalFileSystem.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1257)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1238)
at hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1.copyDirectory(HDFSTestGUI1.java:710)
at hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1.jMenuPasteItemActionPerformed(HDFSTestGUI1.java:446)
at hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1.access$400(HDFSTestGUI1.java:43)
at hdfstest1.HDFSTestGUI1$5.actionPerformed(HDFSTestGUI1.java:172)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
 //constructor
 public HDFSTestGUI1()  {
    try{
        conf1.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf1.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        initComponents();
        setIcon();
        showDate();
        showTime();
        homeBtn.doClick();
        writeBtn1.setVisible(false);
        readBtn.setVisible(false);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Exception::Please check core-site.xml config or " + ex);
    }

     //main method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | 
    IllegalAccessException | 
javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
     java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HDFSTestGUI1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new HDFSTestGUI1().setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

  Logger.getLogger(HDFSTestGUI1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}


private void copyDirectory(String srcPath, String destPath) {
    try {
        Path p1, p2;
        p1 = new Path(srcPath);
        p2 = new Path(destPath);
        if (p1.getFileSystem(conf1).exists(p2)) {
            fs.copyToLocalFile(p1,p2);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Copied 
 Successfully");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Destination path does 
  not Exist::" + p2);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);

Logger.getLogger(HDFSTestGUI1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
<description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Can somebody show me the correct direction?

Comment: The code is long. Can you point us to the error ? Like where exactly are you trying to use the location `user/new1`?

Comment: It is very log code. I am trying to fetch list from localhost:9000 and from gui, I am opening it. Basically I am creating a file explorer where I can list the directories but not able to perform other options. In copyDirectory() method I am getting this exception.
Do let me know if you want more information.

Answer (score 1):

In the copyDirectory method, `fs` is un-defined. You might want to use:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
```

`conf` being `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` object.

Comment: It is defined but as I said I have put only small amount of code. I have used it as global variable.

Comment: @DipeshRaichana Check if you might have accidentally swapped the values for `srcPath` and `destPath` otherwise I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I have used both path(absolute) with hdfs file system. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @DipeshRaichana `copyToLocalFile` is used to copy from HDFS to local file. so your `destPath` should be on your Local File System.

Comment: how do I use same file system for all operations? I just want to display all operations visually in my GUI.

Comment: If you want to copy from one HDFS location to another, you will have to use `FileUtils.copy`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143676/discussion-between-dipesh-raichana-and-philantrovert).

Comment: Chat is blocked, sorry.

Comment: I dont find other methods in doc. such as cut,copy paste rename, delete etc. How would I use those methods using this?

Comment: @DipeshRaichana See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43158156/7224597)